# SQL Server - dm_exec_sessions - last_request_end_time smaller than last_request_start_time

Tags: sql, sql-server, dmv

When using the query below, I can see that for some of the records
returned  `last_request_end_time` is smaller than `last_request_start_time`.

What is the reason for that? Is that condition an indication
of which records represent waiting/blocked sessions?

```
SELECT 
session_id AS "spid",
login_time,
"host_name",
"program_name",
login_name,
nt_user_name,
last_request_start_time,
last_request_end_time
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE
    session_id IN (52, 53);
```

Comment: The last request to start, hasn't ended yet, maybe...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yeah, my question is mainly about that "maybe" part.

Answer (score 2):

This is a big long for a comment but the "maybe" appears to be true.  These fields are documented as:

> **last_request_start_time datetime**
>
> Time at which the last request on the session began. This includes the currently executing request. Is not nullable.
>
> **last_request_end_time datetime**
>
> Time of the last completion of a request on the session. Is nullable.

I just checked on a very quiescent system, and see a row with the same values.  When a request starts, it affects the start time but it doesn't `NULL` the end time.